# Ruta de archivos con python3 en Linux o Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, rutas

tengo una duda no se como se llama esto, no se como buscarlo en internet pero lo que necesito es lo siguiente:

tengo logs y archivos python en diferentes carpetas, por ejemplo la ruta de uno de los logs es la siguiente: `/home/user/Documentos/proyecto/logs/messages.json`

pero cuando alguien mas lo quiera usar la ruta no va a ser la misma, cambiaria por ejemplo a: `home/user123/Descargas/proyecto/logs/messages.json` la ubicación o el path va a ser distinto,

es posible que funcione el programa diciéndole que busque en: `..../proyecto/messages.json` o como puedo manejar esas rutas?

gracias a todos por su atención.

```
from pathlib import Path
import shutil
import datetime


def pathrename():
    d_from = Path("/home/user/Documentos/proyecto/messages.json")
    file = f"{str(datetime.datetime.now())}_{d_from.name}"
    h_for = Path("/home/user/Documentos/proyecto/logs").joinpath(file)
    shutil.move(d_from.resolve(), h_for.resolve())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes probar con las utilidades de Path, asumiendo que estás en Python 3.5+

```
import Path
print(Path.home())
```

Puedes ver [otras opciones aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028904/how-to-get-the-home-directory-in-python).

Con esto obtienes la ruta al directorio propio del usuario.

Si quieres conocer la ruta del script que estás ejecutando tienes el símbolo `__file__`.

Puedes ver más opciones en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1955163/4105601).

Comment: pero no entiendo, osea que al momento de buscar la ruta de los archivos uso home = str(Path.home())   en ese caso llamaria la variable home, /proyecto/logs/archivo.json  ? no me queda claro como se usaria para reemplazar la ruta del ordenador o usuario diferente al desarrollador

Comment: Path.home() devolvería los "/home/user/" y "/home/user123/" de tu ejemplo o "C:\Users\UsuarioABC" en Windows.

Comment: con esta informacion ya tengo el directorio o nombre del usuario, pero como puedo obtener el directorio donde esta el script? puede que este en Documentos, en Descargas, entre otros. hay alguna forma de decirle que autocomplete la direccion o el path de la carpeta del proyecto para atras?

Comment: @DaveNISC he editado mi respuesta para ofrecer más información.